# How can I print a large web page to a single-page pdf with custom dimensions?

Tags: ubuntu, firefox, pdf, printing, html

I am trying to convert [this page](http://docs.neo4j.org/refcard/2.0/) to a single-page, `19 x 13` pdf file.

I am running Firefox under `Ubuntu` and trying to use the `Print To File` option, but it is splitting the web page into multiple pages.

Is there a way to get the page into a single-page pdf with the given dimensions?

Edit: I already tried setting the page dimensions to `19 x 13` using custom page size. 
The only noticeable effect is that each page now has more whitespace, but the page is still split across multiple pages.

Also, I already saw the answer suggesting the [Abduction](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/abduction/) plugin, which works, but I prefer a pdf because it is more scalable.

Answer (score 2):

1. Navigate to the page
2. File > Print (or use <kbd>CTRL</kbd> +<kbd>P</kbd> )
3. Switch to "**Page Setup**" page
4. In "**Page Size**" drop down list choose last option called "**Manage Custom Sizes**"
5. You will see the dialog window with the settings you are looking for:

[image]

**EDIT 1:**

Note that the page has to be small enough to fit in your specified dimensions, otherwise you will still end up having multiple pages in your PDF. If the page does not fit, you have two options:

1. Change the dimensions proportionally (keep same ratio)
2. Use the Scale function in **Page Setup** window and scale down the original page. In this case it is important to untick the option "Ignore Scaling And Shrink To Fit Page Width" on the **Options** page.

Comment: I already tried this and it still split the page into multiple pages. The only difference was that each page now has more whitespace.

Comment: Then please post the settings you used. You should have posted them in your questions.

Comment: Point taken, and updated question.

Comment: I have just tried it and it prints correctly. First thing you need to know that by default **19x13** will result into **19 inches x 13 inches**. This is not enough to fit the contents of the page that you have linked in your question so if by saying 19x13 you mean the ratio, then go for **52x76** [which is **(19*4)x(13*4)**].

Comment: On the other hand, if you want to shrink the whole thing down to 19x13 inches, then you did not phrase your question correctly and you need to scale the contents. I will update my original answer shortly

Comment: When you say "it prints correctly", do you mean that it looks exactly like the browser renders it?

Comment: No, I mean it fits on one page with 19x13 side ratio. This was your initial question. You cannot expect it to look the same as in your browser. if you do, then you have to give up on your ratio requirements, because the ratio of the page within your browser is different. In fact by forcing the ratio in Print Setup you make sure it will not look anything similar to what you see in your browser

Comment: Sorry for changing the question, but suppose that I only care that it looks exactly like it looks in the browser, and that it is a single page pdf?

Comment: Well, this is getting too far out of scope. Here is the answer, that definitely beats it: Take a series of screenshots, stitch them in GIMP, then print as PDF. Will do the job.

Comment: If we leave my sarcasm aside, and you still want to play around with standard printing feature then the key is to set width to some reasonable value and then set length to significantly bigger value to allow the whole page to fit. However you have to remember that HTML is not a printer-friendly format and the way you see the page is the way your browser has rendered it for you. It would have looked different on other device or even on your own PC if you resized browser window.

Comment: I'm amazed there's no plugin to do this - a single giant digital document of my webpage (or other document - eg. a powerpoint) would be so useful if you are never considering physically printing it anyway.

Answer (score 0):

In case the above method doesnot works,

1. Print the webpage as pdf from Mozilla Firefox (without header or footer)
2. Export pdf to excel using Adobe Acrobat DC